# Tailwind custom theme color opacity not being applied

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css

I'm working on a **Reactjs** project that uses **Tailwind CSS** as my CSS framework and I'm trying to build a theme with custom colors.

I defined the colors as CSS variables in the `index.css` file, but setting alpha values does not work for those colors.

Here is the CSS for my color values:

```css
  @layer base {
    :root {
        --base: 26 27 27;
        --light: 43 43 43;
        --lighter: 81 81 81;
        --text-base: 235 235 235;
        --text-inverted: 71 72 72;
        --color-primary: 241 218 19;
        --color-primary-light: 245 226 66;
        --color-danger: 243 75 19;
        --color-danger-light: 245 111 66;
        --color-accent: 242 142 19;
        --color-accent-light: 245 165 66;
        --color-secondary: 235 235 235
       }
    }
```

I configured a custom theme in the `tailwind.config.js` file like below:

```js
 module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                skin: {
                    base: 'rgb(var(--base) / <alpha-value>)',
                    light: 'rgb(var(--light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    primary:'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
                    lprimary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    danger: 'rgb(var(--color-danger) / <alpha-value>)',
                    dangerLight: 'rgb(var(--color-danger-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    accent: 'rgb(var(--color-accent) / <alpha-value>)',
                    laccent: 'rgb(var(--color-accent-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)'
                }
            },
            backgroundColor: {
                skin: {
                    base: 'rgb(var(--base) / <alpha-value>)',
                    light: 'rgb(var(--light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    primary:'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
                    lprimary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    danger: 'rgb(var(--color-danger) / <alpha-value>)',
                    ldanger:'rgb(var(--color-danger-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
                    accent: 'rgb(var(--color-accent) / <alpha-value>)',
                    laccent: 'rgb(var(--color-accent-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                }
            },
            textColor: {
                skin: {
                    base: 'rgb(var(--text-base) / <alpha-value>)',
                    inverted: 'rgb(var(--text-inverted) / <alpha-value>)',
                    primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
                    hover: 'rgb(var(--color-primary-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                    secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
                }
            },
            borderColor: {
                skin: {
                    primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
                    hover: 'rgb(var(--color-primary-light) / <alpha-value>)',
                }
            }
        },
    }};
```

However, when I use a class like `bg-skin-base-100` the alpha value is not applied.

Does anybody know why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Tailwind, 3.14? The `<alpha-value>` approach was just added in v3.1 (https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#easier-css-variable-color-configuration).

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the opacity for a color utility class, you need append a slash and the opacity value (0-100), not a dash. For instance, `bg-skin-base/50` will use the opacity `.5`.

In your case, this would result in the CSS: `color: rgb(26 27 27/.5)`.

Details and examples here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color#changing-the-opacity

Comment: Thanks, @EdLucas. Using bg-skin-base/50 applied opacity value to my elements!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are close, but you need add a function for that in your `tailwind.config.js`. [Here is a playground from Tailwind Labs](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YelhilBeHb), with a function called `withOpacity` in the config. In your tailwind config you can call it when defining a color:

```
base: withOpacity('--base'),
```

You can see the working in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAtaT8BZEAo), from around 17 minutes until the end. They also explain why you should do it this way.

Hope this helps.

Edit: as suggested by [Ed Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287476/ed-lucas), from Tailwind 3.1 on [you can use a different approach](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#easier-css-variable-color-configuration).

Comment: This is no longer necessary in Tailwind CSS version 3.1+. https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#easier-css-variable-color-configuration

Comment: Thanks, @EdLucas! Always nice to learn something when trying to help someone else :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that video and used the `withOpacity`  function. I think the problem was with how I added opacity. I saw tailwind documentation and there was suggested to apply opacity using a `-`

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved the problem adding in my home blade the followung code in the head...

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
```