# Overriding colors of React Component Library that uses TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css, rollupjs

I'm building a React Component Library that uses Rollup and TailwindCSS for styling and each component has a default style based on set color variables in the `tailwind.config.js` file. I want to be able to consume this library in another project and then override the TailwindCSS color variables used in the component library to change the theme without adding a className prop to every single component.

Is it possible to override the color variables in my component library to enable this functionality?

I've attempted to just create duplicate entries in my consumer project's `tailwind.config.js` with the same variable names but using different hex values and it still just seems to compile with colors from the library.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see what you tried in your `tailwind.config.js` and how you are adding the color variables in your project.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same situation. @EdLucas how I am adding colors (in my component library) is extending tailwind colors. 
extend: {
      colors: {
        white: {
          DEFAULT: '#F0F0F0',

And use bg-white in my components.

Comment: @kkonda The OP did not include enough information to figure out what their problem is and your comment above is similarly lacking. I'd recommend creating a new SO question with your particular details.

Comment: I ended up doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831003/tailwind-custom-theme-color-opacity-not-being-applied
With a some javascript to dynamically update the css vars